# JDeveloper Creating Multiple Project in one application

Tags: jdeveloper

I do have a question regarding the JDeveloper what my boss want is to create a system consisting of multiple project in one application in JDeveloper I mean is it possible. because everytime I create an application I can only create 1 project. My boss want me to create let say accounting system and he wants it to be separated per project lets say pettycash system, HRM system an so on but all of this is interconnected to one another when the pettycash system button is clicked the project pettycash system is open and can be use...  Guys if you do have any suggestion or opinion it will be very helpful to me..

Answer (score 0):

An application can be build using multiple projects. A workspace, which is used in JDev as shell around an application, can hold multiple projects which can interact.

As you did not tell which kind of application you want to build (web based, thick client) and which technologies you want to use for that, we can't give a better advice. And it would help to know which jdev version do you use.

Answer (score 0):

From within your application, use the "New Project..." menu item. That will create projects within your application.

[image: New Project Menu]